# jwplayer 5.10 onSeek not being called on iphone browser in fullscreen

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer 5.10 for my website.

When I fastforward a video on seek bar on iphone 6 (ios 8.4), the onSeek function never get called. I noticed when I manually call jwplayer.seek on debugger, the onSeek get called.

The onTime function get called successfully without any problem.

Would anyone please help me on this?

Comment: JW Player 5 is now obsolete, and it had many problems on mobile devices (it was primarily a Flash player). Try JW 6.12, the current version, and see if the problem goes away. (Be aware that the setup attributes and the API are quite different between 5 and 6, so you can't just swap out the script files.)

Comment: @yfeng I'm curious, when you play JW Player 5.10, what interface do you get playing video? Are you forced to watch video fullscreen with the iPhone's default player or can you play the JW Player with it's own skin in a smaller screen (inline)?

Comment: Do you have a link? In JW5 (and 6) the full screen iPhone player will show up when an iPhone, or iPod touch, is used.

Comment: @zer00ne, I have to force users to watch video fullscreen with iPhone's default player. It seems iPhone default player doesn't call the onSeek callback when users are fastforwarding.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer there isn't a link right now to demo the issue. It's a feature I want to add and it's only on my local right now. It seems when video is playing in iPhone's player, the onSeek callback never get called. I'm not sure if this is because compatibility between ios 8 and JW 5.

Comment: Going to have to see an example.